# Simple Jquery Drop-down Menu repeats animation, how can I stop this?

Tags: jquery, animation, drop-down-menu, repeat

Try rolling hovering over the link many times that's what triggers the repeating animation.

JQUERY//

```
    // Wait for the page and all the DOM to be fully loaded
$('body').ready(function() {

            // Add the 'hover' event listener to our drop down class
    $('.dropdown').hover(function() {
                    // When the event is triggered, grab the current element 'this' and
                    // find it's children '.sub_navigation' and display/hide them
        $(this).find('.sub_navigation').slideToggle(); 
    });
});
```

HTML//

```
    <ul id="navigation">
<li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Dropdown</a>
    <ul class="sub_navigation">
        <li><a href="#">Sub Navigation 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Navigation 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Navigation 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Dropdown 2</a>
    <ul class="sub_navigation">
        <li><a href="#">Sub Navigation 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Navigation 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Navigation 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: My question is the subject of this whole post. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something simple here: http://jsfiddle.net/gJmQh/

`is(":visible")` check.

```
$(this).find('.sub_navigation').is(":visible")
```

Hope it fits your cause `:)`

**code**

```
// Wait for the page and all the DOM to be fully loaded
$('body').ready(function() {

    // Add the 'hover' event listener to our drop down class
    $('.dropdown').hover(function() {
        // When the event is triggered, grab the current element 'this' and 
        if ($(this).find('.sub_navigation').is(":visible")) {
            // find it's children '.sub_navigation' and display/hide them
            $(this).find('.sub_navigation').slideUp();
        } else {
            $(this).find('.sub_navigation').slideDown();

        }

    });
});​
```

Comment: @user1758020 Lol flick me a fiddle with your full code on it, I will help you out! `:)`

Comment: Did you only want the menu code or the full file that contains all of my jquery scripts?

Comment: @user1758020 http://jsfiddle.net/9cZBN/ working here - I hope you have include JQ source in your code `:)`

Comment: @keihead I mean this, `:)` or send me the url I will take a look but here is the JQ source `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/ libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` add this line in your code.

Comment: hey @keihead Sup, howz it going! heh here is fine or I can start a chat for you in here lemme know if you online in SO, also what is the issue at the moment? `:)` *Also* your paste bin not visible to me, cheers!

Comment: @keihead I reckon you need 20 points to be in the chartroom, anyhoo, can you flick me the exact issue? What is not working? Or flick me a dump code in jsfiddle, make sure it does make sense, I would be happy to give you hand, :) it's very late my part of world, talk to latters,

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having the `$('.dropdown').hover()` event, try the `mouseenter` and `mouseexit` like this:

```
('.dropdown').on('mouseeneter', function() {
```

and

```
('.dropdown').on('mouseexit', function() {
```

## Edit

Something like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yfm5D/) - [Yfm5D](http://jsfiddle.net/Yfm5D/)

Comment: This would work but not necessary. Hover will work just fine once she defines the second function of the .hover() method.

Comment: :/ on my site this doesn't work either *sigh*. I have a "main-js.js" file where I add all my jquery. should I separate the menu script from the rest? or is that not an issue?

Comment: @user1758020 Did you check the entire code on fiddle link given?

Comment: Yes, I went to the fiddle and copied the new* code. Didn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

[Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/AcJbv/)

You need to define two functions for the `.hover()` to work (hover-in / hover-out).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dropdown').hover(function() {

        $(this).find('.sub_navigation').slideDown();
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('.sub_navigation').slideUp();
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried that but the animation still continues. If you hover over and out 3+ times the animation keeps going when the cursor isn't even on the link...is there a solution to that? @computerarts

Comment: This snippet doesn't disable the menu. However, it still does a funky repeating animation.